# Magento 2.2.8 session_start slow in profiler

Tags: session, customer-session

We have multiple Magento 2.2.8 websites on one domain (domain.com = Website A, domain.com/store = Website B - separate customer accounts, but often people are registered on both).

We're having numerous reports from users than when trying to log into either website they are presented with a white screen. We've debugged this and found that it does load eventually, but in the profiler, the session_start times are 50-300+ seconds; so the website looks broken to users.

It continues to happen, so all subsequent page views are equally slow. It does not happen to every user, however, we've noticed that deleting all rows relating to a users email address in DB.sales_quote allows this to work properly.

Currently, sessions are saved on files. we'd prefer to not move to redis/memcached.

I'm keen to find a solution - has anyone experienced this or is there a good way to debug this?

Comment: Try to disable third party extension one by one and then check. So you get idea if ny extension create issue or not.